# How might I conditionally sort data in one row to its approximate data-match in a second row?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, for-loop

So, I have a data sorting problem.

Essentially, I want to sort the cells of Rows 2 through 48 so that they are beneath their approximate values in Row 1 (the ellipses are used in the below pictures as place holders for all other cells within the row; all Rows, 1 to 48, will extend from EG to IB, making each row a total of 100 cells).

The data will often appear as this:

[image: have]

But I require the data of Rows 2 to 48 to be sorted beneath its Row 1 counterpart in approximate value (within 1.2), like this:

[image: want]

Values are now sorted, using Row 1 as the master row to which all other rows are sorted. Cells within Rows 2-48 must be left blank if no cell value within that Row meets the condition of being within 1.2 of its Row 1 correspondent.

My initial code was written like so:

```
Sub t()

Dim F As Range
Dim Q As Range

For Each F In Range("EG1:IB1").Cells
    For Each Q In Range("EG2:IB2").Cells
        If Q.Value <= (F.Value + 1.2) Then
            F.Offset(1, 0).Value = Q.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Q
Next F

End Sub
```

This code does not produce the desired result, obviously, but I do not know why. The intent was to iteratively check the data values of Row 1 against Row 2, and if a value with the necessary criteria was found in Row 2 (being within 1.2 of the current Row 1 cell value), then place it beneath its correspondent in Row 1.

So, assuming that:

1. Row 1 will have data values in all 100 cells, and
2. Rows 2-48 will *NOT* have data in all 100 cells, and
3. Cells that do not contain data will be empty, and
4. I want to keep the code limited to sorting one row at a time (checking and sorting a single Row against Row 1 per program run, for safety sake)

How can I rewrite (entirely, if need be) my code so that I might sort the data, as exampled in the first picture, to best fit the data organization exampled in the second picture?

Thank you in advance, and please pardon me if this actually turns out to be an incredibly simple solution that I have overlooked!!

Best,

Comment: a) Is there anything in rows 2-48 that is above 598.67123 (i.e. the value in IB1)? Does the data have to be sorted laterally *before* shifting the position?

Comment: @Jeeped ah, right! good question. there are values that exceed the 598.67123. the values beneath row one can be up to 599.99999. to provide further detail, the data is, well, a reaction time task. row 1 represents all of the time values for the stimuli within the program and when they occur precisely in seconds. the values in rows 2-48 are responses to the stimuli. so, since the output did not do it for me, i want to sort the appropriate responses with the initial presentation time of the stimulus for comparison. does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting each row laterally should correct any out-of-order values and 'huddle' them all at the left end of the EG1:IB48 range. After that, inserting a new cell (shifting other values on the row right) should correct the placement.

```
Sub sort_and_push()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")   '<~~ set this correctly!
        With .Range("EG1:IB48")
            With .Rows(1)
                .Cells.sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
            End With
            For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
                .Rows(rw).Cells.sort Key1:=.Rows(rw), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
                For cl = 1 To 99
                    If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then
                        Exit For
                    ElseIf .Cells(rw, cl).Value2 > .Cells(1, cl + 1).Value2 Then
                        .Cells(rw, cl).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    End If
                Next cl
            Next rw
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub t()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim F As Excel.Range
    Dim Q As Excel.Range
    Dim J As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim SortRange As Excel.Range
    Dim HeaderRange As Excel.Range

    Const COL1 As Long = 137
    Const COLN As Long = 236

    ' This is the row you're sorting
    ' You'll probably want to make this a loop
    ' variable to sort all rows
    Const RR As Long = 2

    ' As a safety measure I'm specifying which worksheet to sort
    ' to make sure we don't accidentally sort the wrong data.
    ' Modify this to suit your purposes.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set SortRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(RR, COL1), ws.Cells(RR, COLN))
    Set HeaderRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, COL1), ws.Cells(1, COLN))

    ' As a first step, I'm sorting row 2.
    ' If the values out of order there's a potential to accidentally
    ' overwrite data. For example if you had
    '       EG  EH
    '   1   2   5
    '   2   4   3
    ' moving the 4 in row two to column EH would overwrite the 3.
    ' If the values are already sorted, you could skip this.
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=SortRange, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange SortRange
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    ' I've reversed the nested-ness of the Q and F loops
    ' Also, I'm traversing the Q loop in reverse order to avoid
    For J = COLN To COL1 Step -1
    ' For J = 142 To 137 Step -1    ' short loop for testing
        Set Q = ws.Cells(RR, J)
        ' Skip blank cells
        If Not IsEmpty(Q.Value) Then
            ' Do the comparison to Row 1
            For Each F In HeaderRange.Cells
                If Q.Value <= (F.Value + 1.2) Then
                    ws.Cells(2, F.Column).Value = Q.Value   ' Write to correct column
                    If F.Column <> Q.Column Then
                        Q.Clear           ' Get rid of old value
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next F
        End If
    Next J

    GoTo CleanUp

CleanUp:
        Set F = Nothing
        Set Q = Nothing
        Set SortRange = Nothing
        Set HeaderRange = Nothing
        Set ws = Nothing

Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Hope this helps